# Drools. Slow performance and needs restart. KieServicesClient should call method close or completeConversation?

Tags: drools, kie

We use drools for our business rules but currently as time goes by drools become slower and slower and then we have to restart them. When they become slow we collect dump but we did not see the memory to be increased dramatically. We use java rest client in order to communicate with drools and specifically we use below code

```
 KieServicesClient kieServicesClient = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(conf);

 KieServicesClient ruleClient = kieServicesClient.getServicesClient(RuleServicesClient.class);
```

After communicating with drools should we call `kieServicesClient.close()` or `kieServicesClient.completeConversation()`? If we do not call anything then what will happen? Can drools become slower?

Could you please give some hints how we can investigate why the performance of the drools is deteriorating?

- rules are deployed in Business Central Workbench, v7.47.0.Final

Comment: Please add what Drools version you're using. Also your references to a "rest" client seems to indicate you're using the KieServer or some other REST API rather than local in-memory rules -- can you clarify a bit about how you have your rules deployed?

Comment: Drools are executed in BCW version 7.47.0.Final. So our application uses the rest client in order to execute the rules that exist in a standalone BCW.

Comment: What is BCW? That is not an acronym I'm familiar with.

Comment: Business Central Workbench

Comment: Ah. They changed the name again. Thanks. :)